# Magento2 - Using Luma - Can't add CSS or JS

Tags: magento2, theme, javascript, css, inheritance

new Magento2 installation, went through a whole series of learning where I could not figure out why my default head blocks xml wasn't working to load my custom css/js files... as per the new theme in the documentation.

After re-going over the code, there was nothing wrong... by trial & error,

I figured out that if I made my new theme inherit from **magento/blank**, then my custom css & js would load... but if I inherit from **magento/luma**, *it would not*... so... my question is HOW can I use the Luma theme and then just modify it to suit needs, it's a great starting point, and would cut out weeks of development if we could use this.

So, I created a new theme, and inherit from luma like this:

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
    <title>CVPStyle4</title>
    <parent>Magento/luma</parent>
    <media>
        <preview_image>media/preview.jpg</preview_image>
    </media>
</theme>
```

then I go and regenerate static files via deploy, and my theme is in the backend, and I activate it and it looks like luma, but it does NOT load my custom css/js files, or anything in the default_head_blocks.xml

inside:
**app > design > frontend > myvendor > mytheme > Magento_Theme > layout**

and here's my code in that xml:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
    
    <!--Custom Styles-->
    <css src="css/cvpstyle.css" />
    
    <!--Before-After Script-->
    <link src="js/jquery.twentytwenty.js"/>
    <link src="js/jquery.event.move.js"/>
    
    <!--Font Awesome-->
    <css src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" src_type="url" />
</head>
</page>
```

and no matter how I do it, it will not load and work.

*How can I inherit from luma and add some css/js to customize it?*

## note

I have tried copying the entire luma theme from:

**vendor > magento > theme-frontend-luma**
and then changing the name and such in composer.json, registration.php, and theme.xml - theme sort of loads, (doesn't look quite right) - and STILL won't load any custom CSS/JS from the default_head_blocks.xml

any thoughts? I'd really like to use luma as a base.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First ensure that your store is in 'developer' mode then ensure the case of your theme that should be: VendorName > theme_name

Then since you are working in dev mode ensure to delete these folders (between every change)

```
var/cache - you can deactivate some cache to avoid remove that
var/page_cache - you can deactivate some cache to avoid remove that
var/view_processed
pub/static/frontend/{VendorName}
```

As I say recently in other answer... yes frontend development in M2 is a pain in the back.